# Need to enter telegram code after starting python bot

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot, telethon, telegram-api

I choose heroku for use my simple python script that gets telegram messages and parses them. So when i start the script on heroku it asked for telegram number and confirmation code, but i cant to enter them because i started it by command: `heroku ps:scale bot=1` and have no access to heroku terminal. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to enter code everytime, because once you logged in, it will create a session file. So use that session file.

Comment: heroku filesystem is ephemeral so session file will be deleted after app restart

Answer (score 0):

**I think you need to pass your session string in telethon**

Answer (score 0):

[Official Docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html?highlight=StringSession#different-session-storage)

Process -

- You need to generate a session and save it somewhere like Environmental Variables
- You use the saved session we need `StringSession`

### Generate Session :

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

with TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    print(client.session.save())
```

Save this printed session in environmental variables

### Use the printed session :

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

with TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    # ....
```

By doing this you don't need to generate session again and again